Use access token from Azure AD app to use with sharepoint REST API
I have an Azure AD app registered and my web app requires using both graph-api and REST API to fetch sharepoint account information.
For eg:
https://domain.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/RoleAssignments

Problem is the access token i fetch for graph isnt valid for REST. I basically want to avoid having to register my app on the:
https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

Which asks for an xml block to be added to allow Full Access.
Desired: Single AD app to be used for both graph-api and rest api implementation. Separate tokens are fine.

How are you generating the access token? Are you making use of Client credential flow or user interactive flow?

It is by default required to to give full access in  xml block to fetch the details

Using client credential flow from this url https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/%s/tokens/OAuth/2


Note that: If you are making use of Client credential flow and granting application permissions to the Microsoft Entra ID application, it is mandatory and by default you must grant permissions in the Add-in to allow Full Access to the application.

If you want to avoid registering app in the Add-In and giving full access, then you can grant delegated API permissions and make use of delegated flow as a workaround:
Grant delegated API permission to the Microsoft Entra ID application:

Use the below endpoint to authorize users:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://Domain.sharepoint.com/.default
&state=12345


Generate access token by using below parameters:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://Domain.sharepoint.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms


By using the above access token, you can call the SharePoint Rest API:
https://domain.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/RoleAssignments


